# Deleting empty albums on iOS 13.3 with iFunbox > User File System

Tags: ios, iphone, ios13, ios13.3

My Canon PowerShot G7 X Mark II with the CameraConnect App has created almost 2000 empty albums to my iPhone XS (iOS 13.3).

Is there any way to delete a single/multiple files using iFunbox > User File System to delete/rebuilt photo albums or cache so that all empty folders or at least the folders mentioned would dissappear from my iPhone? Other methods are appriciated as well.

I had no luck with uninstalling CameraConnect App.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a Mac**, you can connect it via USB then on your mac import the photos you want to save from your phone. Then select all (CMD+A) and then delete it.

**If you have Windows**, you can try using the [imyphone application](https://www.imyfone.com/ios-data-erase/how-to-delete-albums-from-your-iphone/)

Best of luck!

Comment: No luck at all. There is some restrictions when it comes to 3rd party software and manipulating filesystem. This can be made via iFunbox but I am not sure what to delete.